# Boost serialization - Serialize noncopyable but movable objects?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, noncopyable, movable

Is it possible somehow?
It doesnt work out of the box since it tries to copy objects when the object gets unserialized

Update 1: These objects are noncopyable just because they allocate memory, once it is allocated I dont see any reason to copy when it can be moved. The unserialization part should be kept as fast as possible.

Comment: Usually objects are noncopyable because they have internal state that can not be copied or re-created, so the question here is: what makes your object noncopyable, and does that semantically prevent regeneration from a serialized state? and if not, then why is it noncopyable?

Comment: A solution is to serialize boost::shared_ptr<CMyNonCopyableClass>

Comment: hmm... will try with pointers, dont sure it suits my needs in this case

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once some time ago, and IIRC I did not find any solution to this, so instead I unserialized an object of another type and fed that into the actual object's construtor. That other type was designed just to make deserialization fast and move its contents to the acutal object.